# Is enum to Enum boxing or just type casting

Tags: c#, enums, casting, boxing

I'm wondering if casting to Enum will box enum or not

So should I write expression bodied member to reduce size of my objects.

```
public Fruit FruitType => (Fruit) Type; // unboxing?
public override Enum Type => (Fruit) (Data[0] & 0xF0); // boxing?
```

Or have property to prevent boxing and unboxing?

```
public Fruit FruitType => (Fruit) (Data[0] & 0xF0);
public override Enum Type { get; } = (Fruit) (Data[0] & 0xF0); // assigned once.
```

Assuming I have thousands of instances. and this property is used about 60 thousand times.

Comment: To avoid code duplication, you might want to use your second option and define Type as `public override Enum Type { get; } => FruitType;`. The jitter will probably inline the `FruitType` getter, so there should be no performance penalty.

Comment: interesting point. didn't thought of jitter. if jitter is smart enough it may be able to optimize in other way around. `public Fruit FruitType => (Fruit) Type;` which `Type` basically becomes `(Fruit) (Data[0] & 0xF0)` @Heinzi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, the value is boxed.**

Section 4.3.1 "Boxing conversions" of [the C# spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) states:

> A boxing conversion permits a value-type to be implicitly converted to a reference-type. The following boxing conversions exist:
>
> [...]
>
> - From any enum-type to the type `System.Enum`.
>
> [...]